# how to pass the body to a rest API

Tags: json, api, rest

I can run the following GET

```
https://myapi/aaa/?a=270&b=dog&c=animal
```

But I wonder how to save the parameters to a json body and pass to API. That is, what I call is
`https://myapi/aaa/` with body

```
{
    "a": 270,
    "b": "dog",
    "c": "animal"
}
```

But the response say "Please provide value for a".
Also suppose parameter a and b have multiple values, how to write the request:

I tried `https://myapi/aaa/?a=${270,271}&b=${dog,cat}&c=animal` but with no luck.

Comment: Which technology you are working at? Any framework, programming language?

Comment: I am using a firefox plugin RESTClient

Answer (score 1):

I think you add an extra "/" after aaa. try this:

https://myapi/aaa?a=270&b=cat&c=animal

If you want to send multiple parameters you can do this:

https://myapi/aaa?a=270&a=271&b=cat&b=dog&c=animal

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass the JSON data in the body as a POST request.But if you still want to pass this as a parameter in URL,you will have to encode your URL like below just for example:-

for ex json is :->{"name":"ABC","id":"1"}

testurl:80/service?data=%7B%22name%22%3A%22ABC%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D